# How to install Multiple PHP versions on i686?

Tags: php, centos6

Below is my Server installation info:
Operating system    CentOS Linux 6.9
Webmin version  1.831
Virtualmin version  5.07.gpl
Kernel and CPU  Linux 2.6.32-573.el6.i686 on i686

I was trying to install multiple PHP versions on my server as per Docs provided here ( https://www.virtualmin.com/documentation/web/multiplephp )

But on very first step I get

[root@server ~]# yum install centos-release-scl
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, security
Setting up Install Process
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * base: mirror.clarkson.edu
 * extras: mirror.compevo.com
 * updates: linux.mirrors.es.net
No package centos-release-scl available.
Error: Nothing to do

Any Suggestion
Regards

Rizwan

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible with that approach. The site you linked to clearly wrote

> Note that the repository providing these packages currently only provides 64 bit packages. If you are using 32 bit CentOS, there are unfortunately no PHP packages for that.

Comment: So is there any way to install multiple PHP versions on 32 bit centos

Comment: Not easily. Using SCL has the advantage that you can switch between versions. The other common repos for alternative PHP versions are meant to replace the stock PHP install, not to complement it. Of course, you can always install manually or into another path, but this gets *really* complicated if you want to configure your web server to use different PHP versions for different paths. Why do you need this anyway?